# how to find the index for a quantile

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a pandas series and I want to find the index value that represents the quantile.

If I have:

```
np.random.seed(8)
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(6), ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
s

a    0.873429
b    0.968541
c    0.869195
d    0.530856
e    0.232728
f    0.011399
dtype: float64
```

And do

```
s.quantile(.5)
```

I get

```
0.70002511588475946
```

What I want to know is what is the index value of `s` that represents the point just before that quantile value.  In this case I know the index value should be `d`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sort_values`, reverse the order, find all that are less than or equal to the quantile calculated, then find the `idxmax`.

```
(s.sort_values()[::-1] <= s.quantile(.5)).idxmax()
```

Or:

```
(s.sort_values(ascending=False) <= s.quantile(.5)).idxmax()
```

We can functionalize it:

```
def idxquantile(s, q=0.5, *args, **kwargs):
    qv = s.quantile(q, *args, **kwargs)
    return (s.sort_values()[::-1] <= qv).idxmax()

idxquantile(s)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you set the `interpolation` argument to `'lower'`, `'higher'`, or `'nearest'` then the problem can be solved a bit more simply as:

```
s[s == s.quantile(.5, interpolation='lower')]
```

I'd guess this method is a fair bit faster than piRSquared's solution as well